# Minimizing a Matrix

Tags: functions, matrix, mathematical-optimization

```
pnorm[A_, p_] := Module[{m, n, x, y, f, ans, ret},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[A];
  y = Array[x, n];
  f = Norm[A.y, p]/Norm[y, p] // FullSimplify;
  ans = Maximize[f, Array[x, n]] // N;
  ret = Part[ans, 1];
  ret
]

findD[L_, c_, \[Lambda]_, p_] := Module[{B, M, w, pp, ans},
  M = Array[B, Dimensions[L]];
  w = Tr[c.(Transpose[M])];
  pp = pnorm[L - M, p] // FullSimplify;
  ans = Minimize[Hold[pp + \[Lambda] w], 
    Flatten[Array[B, Dimensions[L]]]] // N;
  ans
]

findD[{{3, 8}, {2, 5}}, {{9, 1}, {3, 6}}, .5, 3]

During evaluation of In[44]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value 6.59387       +1/((Abs[<<1>>]^3+<<1>>^3)/(Abs[<<1>>]^3+<<1>>^3))^(1/3) is not a number at {B$33209[1,1],B$33209[1,2],B$33209[2,1],B$33209[2,2]} = {0.643476,0.766972,0.280303,0.964763}. >>

During evaluation of In[44]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value 1/((Abs[<<1>>]^3+<<1>>^3)/(Abs[<<1>>]^3+<<1>>^3))^(1/3)+0.5 (9 B$33209[1,1]+B$33209[1,2]+3 B$33209[2,1]+6 B$33209[2,2]) is not a number at {B$33209[1.,1.],B$33209[1.,2.],B$33209[2.,1.],B$33209[2.,2.]} = {0.643476,0.766972,0.280303,0.964763}. >>

During evaluation of In[44]:= NMinimize::nnum: The function value 1/((Abs[<<1>>]^3+<<1>>^3)/(Abs[<<1>>]^3+<<1>>^3))^(1/3)+0.5 (9 B$33209[1,1]+B$33209[1,2]+3 B$33209[2,1]+6 B$33209[2,2]) is not a number at {B$33209[1.,1.],B$33209[1.,2.],B$33209[2.,1.],B$33209[2.,2.]} = {0.643476,0.766972,0.280303,0.964763}. >>

During evaluation of In[44]:= General::stop: Further output of NMinimize::nnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Minimize[
 Hold[pp$33209 + 0.5 w$33209], {B$33209[1., 1.], B$33209[1., 2.], 
 B$33209[2., 1.], B$33209[2., 2.]}]
```

The code above is trying to find a matrix $\mathbf M$ which minimizes $\|\mathbf L-\mathbf M\|_p + \lambda\,\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf C\mathbf M^\top)$. However, the usage of `Minimize` in the `findD` function is giving me problems. Does anyone know how to fix the "not a number" problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `_?NumericQ` in your function definition

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make `pnorm` into a black-box function so that it never tries to evaluate symbolically. Also it is probably worthwhile to use `NMinimize/NMaximize` in both. Finally the minimax process seems to behave better if you take pth powers in the inner optimization.

```
pnorm[aa_, p_] /; MatrixQ[aa, Element[N[#], Reals] &] := Module[
  {m, n, x, y, f, ans},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[aa];
  y = Array[x, n];
  f = Total[Abs[aa.y]^p]/Total[Abs[y]^p];
  ans = NMaximize[f, y];
  ans[[1]]]

findD[ll_, c_, \[Lambda]_, p_] := Module[
  {bb, mm, w, ans},
  mm = Array[bb, Dimensions[ll]];
  w = Tr[c.(Transpose[mm])];
  pp = pnorm[ll - mm, p];
  ans = NMinimize[pnorm[ll - mm, p] + \[Lambda] w, Flatten[mm]];
  ans]
```

Your example:

```
findD[{{3, 8}, {2, 5}}, {{9, 1}, {3, 6}}, .5, 3]

(* {86.9382369925, {bb$7195688[1, 1] -> 2.99883475189, 
      bb$7195688[1, 2] -> 4.10214829344, 
  bb$7195688[2, 1] -> -1.89824492827, 
      bb$7195688[2, 2] -> 5.00101503916}} *)
```

--- edit ---

Here is code that seems to work better.

```
pnorm[aa_, p_] /; MatrixQ[aa, Element[N[#], Reals] &] := Module[
  {m, n, x, y, f, ans},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[aa];
  y = Array[x, n];
  f = Total[Abs[aa.y]^p]/Total[Abs[y]^p];
  ans = FindMaximum[f, y];
  {ans[[1]]^(1/p), y /. ans[[2]]}]

findD[ll_, c_, \[Lambda]_, p_] := Module[
  {bb, mm, obj, ans},
  mm = Array[bb, Dimensions[ll]];
  obj[mat_?(MatrixQ[#, Element[N[#], Reals] &] &), lmat_, cmat_, 
    pval_, lam_] :=
   Module[{res = pnorm[lmat - mat, pval]},
    res[[1]] + lam*Total[Abs[Flatten[cmat*Transpose[mat]]]]];
  ans = FindMinimum[Evaluate[obj[mm, ll, c, p, \[Lambda]]], 
    Flatten[mm]];
  ans]

findD[{{3, 8}, {2, 5}}, {{9, 1}, {3, 6}}, .5, 3]

(* Out[201]= {9.93991501159, {bb$39780695[1, 1] -> 0.00147967770299, 
      bb$39780695[1, 2] -> 0.0190392337428, 
  bb$39780695[2, 1] -> -2.33558050383*10^-9, 
      bb$39780695[2, 2] -> -0.00620592593044}} *)
```

One thing to note is that I used absolute values for terms in the second part of the objective function. Else i think it can be arbitrarily small.

I also return the maximizing values for the inner optimization. This is from prior experiments, not shown, that also figured sizes of vectors in the objective, to penalize for getting too small. That seems not to be needed in this most recent version but thought I'd leave that there in case you do decide to account for such vector sizes.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer! One thing though: the `pnorm` you have here outputs a different answer than my original one. It seems like yours just raises the elements to the pth power. Doesn't a p-norm also involve taking the pth root of the sum?

Comment: Yes it does. Minimizing one is equivalent to minimizing the other (it's a monotonic function) but this change of mine messes up the result. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: It seems quite unstable and can give hugely negative results when I change to account for pth roots. Is there any chance that the additive term was meant to be `lambda*Tr[mm.c.(Transpose[mm])]`? That seems to make it give plausible results quickly.

Comment: Well the model I'm trying to minimize is `sum_i(sum_j(c_ij * mm_ij))` <- this is equivalent to `Tr[c.(Transpose[mm])]`

But I do see what you mean about the pth root being unnecessary if I only want argmin

Comment: Okay. I'm still getting results that do not seem to be playing nicely with the code. Will have another look tomorrow.

Comment: How very odd. I did my own tests, using OP's implementation of the matrix $p$-norm, and an implementation adapted from some old MATLAB code, and I keep getting `NMinimize::cvdiv` errors. @Muhammad, would you happen to have results of this optimization that are already known to be correct, for checking purposes?

Comment: Somehow I'm not terribly sure that replacing `Tr[c.Transpose[mm]]` with `Total[Abs[Flatten[cmat*Transpose[mat]]]]` yields an equivalent optimization problem...

Comment: @J.M. I had intended: `Total[Abs[Flatten[cmat*mat]]]`, that is, no transposing. It is still a different problem in that I used `Abs` (and made mention of this). The reason was that otherwise I was getting results arnitrarily negative with matrix values that were huge. Whether that is acceptable or unexpected depends on the actual proble details of course; I was guessing it was not the anticipated result, and was guessing as to the needed adjustment to the problem specification.