# Array element problem in optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation, index

I have the following piece of code in Mathematica:

```
a = {1, 2};

b = {2, 3};

f[i_, j_] := a[[i]]^2 + b[[j]]^2;

Maximize[{f[i, j], 1 <= i <= 2 && 1 <= j <= 2}, {i, j}, Integers]
```

By running it I get:

> Part::pspec: Part specification i is neither a machine-sized integer
>   nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>
>
> Part::pspec: Part specification j is neither a machine-sized integer
>   nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See question # 25152: [Minimizing a Matrix](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25152/)

Comment: Could you please explain it more with a simple code? Tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues. One is that you need to bypass symbolic processing since entities like `a[[i]]` (with `i` symbolic) are not defined. We do this by forcing `f` to only work with explicit `Integer` inputs.

```
a = {1, 2};
b = {2, 3};
f[i_Integer, j_Integer] := a[[i]]^2 + b[[j]]^2;
```

The scond issue is that we now have an objective that is, in a sense, a procedural function. The function `Minimize` will not be able to do anything with this. But the numeric variant `NMinimize` can work with it.

```
NMaximize[{f[i, j], 1 <= i <= 2 && 1 <= j <= 2 && i \[Element] Integers && j \[Element] Integers}, {i, j}]

(* Out[228]= {13., {i -> 2, j -> 2}} *)
```